# this.setState is not working when using firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the state to get value from the firebase database but I think there is some problem while doing it.

```
const dbRef=firebase.database().ref().child('profiles').child(user.uid).child('displayName') 
dbRef.on('value',snapshot=>{ 
  this.setState({ profile:{ position:snapshot.val() } }) 
}) 
console.log(this.state)
```

Comment: const dbRef=firebase.database().ref().child('profiles').child(user.uid).child('displayName')
dbRef.on('value',snapshot=>{
    this.setState({
        profile:{
            position:snapshot.val()
        }
    })
})
console.log(this.state)here  is the code

Answer (score 0):

Both loading data from Firebase and setting the state of React are asynchronous operations. This means that your main code continues to run, while the data is being loaded, or the state is being modified.

You can learn a lot about such asynchronous code, by adding some simple logging statements in your current code:

```
const dbRef=firebase.database().ref().child('profiles').child(user.uid).child('displayName') 
console.log("Before starting listener");
dbRef.on('value',snapshot=>{ 
  console.log("Got data, start to set state");

  this.setState({ profile:{ position:snapshot.val() } }, function() {
    console.log("The state has been set");
  }) 

  console.log("Started to set state");
}) 
console.log("After starting listener");
```

The new function I added to `setState` is a callback that is called after the state has been modified, similar to how Firebase has a callback that is called after the data comes back fro. the database.

When you run the above code, the output is:

> Before starting listener
>
> After starting listener
>
> Got data, start to set state
>
> Started to set state
>
> The state has been set

This is probably not the order you expected, but it is completely normal for asynchronous operations. The callback functions you pass in get called out of the normal operating sequence, once the asynchronous operation completes.

This means that any code that needs to run after the state has been set, which in turn depends on the database data, needs to be inside the inner callback that I added in my code above.